# Java - Change value of a class variable for every existing and for every new created object of this class?

Tags: java, class, object

I'm new to Java and I want to change a class variable for every existing and every new object without iterating over every object.

```
public class SomeClass {

    private double handlingFee = 0.015;

    public SomeClass(...) {
        ...
    }
```

The class variable here is the `handlingFee` and I have a Collection (ArrayList) in another class to store these class objects. Is that somehow possible?

And could you tell me how to change the value then? Do I have to iterate every object?

Comment: Make it `static`?

Comment: just to clarify: by saying 'for every existing and every new object' you mean, you have like an array of this objects?

Comment: I have a Collection (ArrayList) where I store all objects @IlyaMaier

Comment: then @jkeeraa another question: why do you store this variable in class, when it should be equal for all the instances...? Why not putting it somewhere else, so that you can access it directly... or maybe making it static as Johannes Kuhn mentioned

Comment: @JohannesKuhn do I have to iterate over every object then or is there the possibility to change a class variable?

Comment: Well my insecurity is that this won't be done for every existing object without iterating, am I right?

Comment: @jkeeraa I suggest you [read what a `static` class variable is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, a point about terminology. In your code, handlingFee is not a class variable; it's an instance variable. To make it a class variable, declare it as static. A static variable (properly called a static field) exists as one instance for the whole class. All objects of that class will share the single instance.

Second, it sounds as if your design is not quite right. For example, your class 'SomeClass' may represent a bank customer. You shouldn't keep handlingFee in the Customer class; it belongs in a BankAccount class, which is something that a number of Customer objects hold references to.

Comment: Thank you very much, also for your explanation! Helped me a lot, not only concerning this issue!

Answer (score -1):

You must iterate over every instance in the collection (and make a setter/getter for handlingFee)

For example:

```
List<SomeClass> myCollection = ...
for (SomeClass obj : collection) {
    obj.setHandlingFee(0.3d);
}
```

or, shorter, with streams API

```
myCollection.forEach(obj -> obj.setHandlingFee(0.3d))
```